# Java: Implementing search function. Return fails if not found

Tags: java, search, return

I am trying to implement a search function. The function returns an object of type Prestamo if it finds a matching element. The function shouldn't return anything if nothing is found, but I get (of course) an error complaining about a missing return statement. How is this kind of problem solved? I guess Try-catch could be my friend for this, but I am struggling to understand that syntax.

This is my code:

```
    public Prestamo buscarPrestamoPorUUID(UUID idPrestamo, ArrayList<Prestamo> listaBuscar) {
    Iterator<Prestamo> it = listaBuscar.iterator();
    Prestamo esteElemento;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        esteElemento = it.next();
        if (esteElemento.getActivo() && esteElemento.getIdPrestamo().equals(idPrestamo)) {
            return esteElemento;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Typically, you would `return null` after your while loop, which would cause the method to return `null` if no element with the desired `UUID` was found.

Comment: to the compiler, that if condition may never resolve to true. If that were to happen, then it would never reach the return statement. Therefore, it says missing return statement. You need to make sure that no matter what occurs, the code will reach a return statement at some point. I believe you can simply put "return;" (though it's been a while since I worked with java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, the control over a method must end in one of two ways:

1. A `return` statement, which returns an object of the type declared in the method signature OR null
2. A thrown exception (if the Exception does not extend RuntimeException, it must be declared in the method signature).

To resolve your compilation error, you need to do one of the two. If you want to do the former, it'd probably look something like this:

```
public Prestamo buscarPrestamoPorUUID(UUID idPrestamo, ArrayList<Prestamo> listaBuscar) {
    Iterator<Prestamo> it = listaBuscar.iterator();
    Prestamo esteElemento;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        esteElemento = it.next();
        if (esteElemento.getActivo() && esteElemento.getIdPrestamo().equals(idPrestamo)) {
            return esteElemento;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Just be sure that the logic that invokes this method is prepared to handle null.

If you want to do the second, you'd do something like this:

```
public Prestamo buscarPrestamoPorUUID(UUID idPrestamo, ArrayList<Prestamo> listaBuscar) {
    Iterator<Prestamo> it = listaBuscar.iterator();
    Prestamo esteElemento;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        esteElemento = it.next();
        if (esteElemento.getActivo() && esteElemento.getIdPrestamo().equals(idPrestamo)) {
            return esteElemento;
        }
    }

    throw new RuntimeException("Didn't find an entity with the provided UUID!");
}
```

I personally prefer the former to the latter. It's a perfectly-valid use of null, and it makes the method easier to use than having to worry about uncaught exceptions. Regardless, note how that either implementation reaches a `return` or `throw` statement eventually. That's what your compiler checks for.

(P.S.: You can replace your while-loop with a for-each loop for code clarity.)

Answer (score 0):

You could have it return null when no match is found.  This would require the caller of the buscarPrestamoPorUUID() method to do a test for null and handle appropriately using a try/catch or some other way to handle it.  ie:

```
Prestamo test = buscarPrestamoPorUUID(someID, someList);

if(test == null)
   { /* handle no match found */ }
else
   { /* handle result found */ }
```